# Node not calling the correct URL, API works fine in POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, backend

I have a few APIs:

This one works correctly:

```
//GET TIMELINE POSTS
router.get('/timeline/:userId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const currentUser = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
    const userPosts = await Post.find({ userId: currentUser._id });

    const friendPosts = await Promise.all(
      currentUser.following.map((friendId) => {
        return Post.find({ userId: friendId });
      })
    );

    res.status(200).json(userPosts.concat(...friendPosts));
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//GET User's all POSTS
router.get('/profile/:username', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username });
    const posts = await Post.find({ userId: user._id });

    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

This line calls the APIs:

```
const res = username 
            ?  await axios.get("posts/profile/" + username) 
            : await axios.get("posts/timeline/6120b0e09308d933dd1c");
```

When username is not provided the timeline api is called which works fine both in app and postman.
The url for the timeline api is:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/posts/timeline/6120b0e09308d933dd1c
```

But when I need to get posts for the user, the correct api which works fine in postman is:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/posts/profile/matt
```

but when the API is called from the app code for which is mentioned above, it adds extra words to the URL, here is what I see in VSCode when it is running:

```
:ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2021:06:28:20 +0000] "GET /api/profile/posts/profile/matt HTTP/1.1" 404 169
```

it should go to /api/posts/profile/matt but instead, it goes to the above-mentioned one

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          <Register />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/profile/:username">
          <Profile />
        </Route>
     </Switch>
</Router>
```

Why is it that the 1st API works fine but the 2nd one adds extra words to the URL?

Comment: Can you share the code where you call the route in React?

Comment: @LucaPizzini in the code above I store the posts I get in 
const res (see above), I use the ternary operator when I want to get posts for that user,
the issue is although the username is passed in the api, as can be seen in vscode output, but it adds an extra /profile before posts, whereas it should be just api/posts/profile/username, the api is working fine though with correct url

Comment: Also, the request is I don't know why is going to localhost:3000,
it should go to localhost:8000, the call for the other APIs go to 8000,
this is what I see in chrome console: xhr.js:210 GET http://localhost:3000/profile/posts/profile/matt 404 (Not Found)